# Place an image on object (Pseudo-3D)

Tags: jquery, image

I would be very grateful if someone can point me to a plugin that places an image on an object. Specifically, I need that the uploaded image will appear on a bottle in pseudo-3d view. I'm a jQuery newbie so it seems impossible to me to write such an difficult plugin on my own.
An exampe what it should look like:

[image]

**Edit:** The mug example to show what i meant by a pseudo-3d.
[image]

Comment: could you draw yourself what you want? I mean if you wanted to do it yourself could you do it with a simple pen and paper? do you need to render a full 3D object? Pseudo 3D can be so many things. take a look at www.threejs.org

Comment: You're right, sorry. I've updated the post and added a picture.

Comment: Is that bottle static or have to rotate ?

Comment: It's static. Otherwise i would be looking for a 360°-plugin :)

Comment: As of the current it's still not clear, what you mean by "pseudo-3d view"

Comment: Right now for me it's just 2 layers of flat images. Something along this my post

Comment: I meant the situation, where the photo is not a rectangle. See the mug example
http://s15.postimg.org/xumtf5xcb/Unbenannt.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways:

- server-side, using eg. [PHP image manipulation functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php): you load the background (bottle image) and overlay the client's uploaded pic. This is my preferred way because you can serve a proper image;
- client-side using a 3 layers workaround:

  - bottom-most: image of the bottle with an empty label
  - intermediate layer: client's uploaded picture
  - topmost layer: PNG-24 flavour of the same bottle pic, with a transparent "hole" in the place of the label, so that you can see the "label" (that is, the client's uploaded pic) through it.

**Disclaimer:** what follows is not advertising, I mention it just for your reference.

I have done something similar for [a website](http://emotybags.it/my-emoty.php) allowing customers to "etch" their own photos on bags. I've used a PHP backend to generate bags thumbnails, and [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) (in conjunction with [the Raphael free transfrom](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform) plugin) for the interactive placement of pictures on the bags.

Comment: Thx a lot. I will take a look at the Raphael.js.

Answer (score 0):

Some structure first :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="bottle"></div>
    <div id="tag"></div>
</div>
```

then you set styles :

```
#container{
    position:relative
}
#bottle{
    background: [your bottle image here, no transparency needed]
    z-index:0;
}
#tag{
    position:absolute;
    top: [whatever px];
    left: [another px];
    background: [your tag image here with transparent bg]
    z-index:100;
}
```